# Android App registration / Authorisation

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I am quite new to android and recently started building an application which requires

- Registration using a google id.
- Continuous interaction with a back-end server.

For the registration , i was wondering if it is possible to have a python webapp  on Google App Engine which has the OAUTH2 authentication .

This page if opened in a webview should return the token to GAE (please correct me if i am wrong here , because i am not sure the token won't just go directly to the app).

Then again on the backend i generate a token(newly generated) and update the user tables with this new token and pass this onwards to the application.

Every subsequent request made by the app will be referenced using this token.

Is this feasible or is there a better standard way to do it (i do not want to use the login info already stored in the phone) ?

Also , how can i get information from a google account(name,email) like Facebook has access to the graph is there a google counterpart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you implement your Android app using WebView. This means that the app interacts with the server the same way as the built-in Android web-browser. As a result you don't need to add anything special to your Android app with regards to authentication.

### Built-in Users service

In GAE, you get out-of-the-box support for three different types of authentication where all of them are designed in a way that your app doesn't store user credentials but rely on user authentication from identity providers:

- Google Accounts (e.g. jonny@gmail.com)
- Google Apps Domain (e.g. jonny@mydomain.com hosted in Google Apps)
- or Federated Login (a.k.a. OpenID, e.g. Google, Yahoo!), which is going to be replaced by Login with oAuth2 (OpenID Connect)

All three types allow your app only access to very basic information of the user. Enough to match a returning user of your GAE app to their data, and an email address or unique ID, but that's it. For more, see below (oAuth2 consumer).

In appengine console, you can select your preferred authentication type in page Administration > Application Settings.

Whatever of these types you use, in your Python code you can use GAE's [Users service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) which will deal with the authentication of your users. Basically, you just write something like:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

user = users.get_current_user()
if not user:
    # The user is not signed in.
else:
    print "Hello, %s!" % user.nickname()
```

On development server, you will be prompted with a dummy login page for requests where you require login or admin login. In live environment they will be replaced by GAE with real login page flow. There are also articles linked in the docs with HTML/JS examples if you want to show custom login pages to your users, for example [User Experience summary for Federated Login](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/summary)

### oAuth2 for authentication and authorization with Google

Regarding oAuth2, with the built-in authentication it is rather easy to integrate the builtin [oAuth service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/), so your GAE app becomes a service provider, i.e. a user of your GAE app can share data with any 3rd party app or website through some simple API. You also can have your GAE app consume data that your users have stored somewhere else (e.g. Google) and they want to share with your [GAE app (consumer)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). If you are especially interested into accessing user data in Google services, there is this [good overview](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/GettingStarted).

### Custom user management

Finally, you could implement your own authentication mechanism, rather than relying (and depending) on GAE features. For example you can implement your [custom user management based on webapp2](http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/). This means that you have control of the user-accounts and credentials, but aside of eventual security risks the disadvantage is that it can be really hard and tricky to integrate services and APIs like Google Cloud Endpoints.